# Cannot store information from form to database

Tags: php, html, database

I'm making a shopping cart where when the user adds an item to their cart, it is saved to the database. I have placed all the needed information within the  tag. Some of the information is repeated as pure text and as hidden inputs. The problem is that when I add an item to the cart, it does say "Item added" however doesn't actually add any information to the database. I have tested whether it was being caused by the images or the price etc. It only functioned as intended when I left nothing but the order_quantity.

**Here is the store page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Store</title>
        <link href="../styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <center><img src="../images/logo.png"></a></center>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <center><h3><li>Store</li>
                    <li><a href="cart.php">Cart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="userorders.php">My orders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li></h3></center>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <div class="left">
            <ul>
                <h4><li>Completes</li>
                <li><a href="decksstore.php">Decks</li>
                <li><a href="wheelsstore.php">Wheels</a></li>
                <li><a href="bearingsstore.php">Bearings</a></li>
                <li><a href="trucksstore.php">Trucks</a></li>
                <li><a href="hardwarestore.php">Hardware</a></li></h4>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="main">
        <br>
            <?php
                require_once('../../connect.php');

                $select = "SELECT * FROM tblcompletes";
                $response = mysqli_query($dbc, $select);

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response))
                {

                    echo '<div class="buyproducts">  
                        <form method="post" action="addtocart.php">
                            <div style="border:1px solid white; background-color:white; border-radius:20px; padding:20px;" align="center">  
                                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['product_image'] ).'" class="img-responsive">
                                <h4 class="text-info">'.$row['product_name'].'</h4>
                                <h4 class="text-danger">$'.$row['product_price'].'</h4>
                                <h4>'.$row['product_quantity'].' in stock</h4> 
                                Quantity: <input type="text" name="order_quantity" class="form-control" value="1">  
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="'.$row["product_ID"].'">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_image" value="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['product_image'] ).'" class="img-responsive">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="'.$row["product_name"].'">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="'.$row["product_price"].'">
                                <input type="submit" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn-success" value="Add to cart">
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>';

                }
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here is the action file:

```
<?php
    require_once('../../connect.php');

    $hidden_id = $_POST['product_ID'];
    $hidden_image = $_POST['product_image'];
    $hidden_name = $_POST['product_name'];
    $hidden_price = $_POST['product_price'];
    $order_quantity = $_POST['order_quantity'];
    $user_email = $_COOKIE['user_email'];

    if ($order_quantity == NULL) 
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Please enter a valid value"); window.location="completesstore.php"; </script>';
    }

    else
    {
        $addtocart = "INSERT INTO tblorders (product_ID, product_iamge, product_name, product_price, order_quantity, user_email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $addtocart);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "issdis", $hidden_id, $hidden_image, $hidden_name, $hidden_price, $order_quantity, $user_email);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Item added"); window.location="completesstore.php"; </script>';

    }

    mysqli_st_close($stmt);
    mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is error your are getting?

Comment: No error; I am just unable to save the information to the database when the form is submitted (using the add to cart button).

Comment: NSERT INTO tblorders (product_ID, product_iamge, product_name, product_price, order_quantity, user_email) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

---- What the '?'  are for ?

Comment: They show that the six values are unknown and whatever is submitted is saved.

Comment: check the below answer, you don't have same name in form and post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$hidden_id = $_POST['product_ID'];
$hidden_image = $_POST['product_image'];
$hidden_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$hidden_price = $_POST['product_price'];
$order_quantity = $_POST['order_quantity'];
$user_email = $_COOKIE['user_email'];
```

To

```
$hidden_id = $_POST['hidden_id'];
$hidden_image = $_POST['hidden_image'];
$hidden_name = $_POST['hidden_name'];
$hidden_price = $_POST['hidden_price'];
$order_quantity = $_POST['order_quantity'];
$user_email = $_COOKIE['user_email'];
```

`name` attributes used in `form` differ in **addtocart.php** file.

Comment: This was the mistake you did while saving it to **addtocart.php** file. I'm not sure about retrieving `$user_email = $_COOKIE['user_email'];`. And, Please Explain  "*.. didn't solve the issue*" . @Dave

Comment: Update: I have tested your answer again without sending the image information. This has solved the issue. If you are curious, I have the user email set as a cookie on logon which I then use to identify the user who ordered the item. With that aside, thank you so much for pointing out my mistake, I really appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

update your action file with following code :

```
$hidden_id = $_POST['product_ID'];
$hidden_image = $_POST['product_image'];
$hidden_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$hidden_price = $_POST['product_price'];
$order_quantity = $_POST['order_quantity'];
$user_email = $_COOKIE['user_email'];
```

replace above code to :

```
$hidden_id = $_POST['hidden_id'];
$hidden_image = $_POST['hidden_image'];
$hidden_name = $_POST['hidden_name'];
$hidden_price = $_POST['hidden_price'];
$order_quantity = $_POST['order_quantity'];
$user_email = $_COOKIE['user_email'];
```

Comment: What is new in your answer @bharat. How it's differing from the answer given below?

Comment: sorry ,, but didnt refresh page when i answered to question

Comment: Thank you as well.

Answer (score 0):

add some name into your button example:

```
<input type="submit" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn-success" value="Add to cart" name="Submit">
```

then to your addtocart.php add this:

```
if(isset($_Submit['Submit'])){
$hidden_id = $_POST['product_ID'];
$hidden_image = $_POST['product_image'];
$hidden_name = $_POST['product_name'];
$hidden_price = $_POST['product_price'];
$order_quantity = $_POST['order_quantity'];
$user_email = $_COOKIE['user_email'];}
```

and just make sure you are connected to your database.